# Paw app not rending requests

Tags: paw-app

I just update Paw to last version 3.0.8 but I can't send new requests anymore.
All the times I try to send a request the following message is shown:

```
No HTTP Exchange

There are no HTTP Exchanges in the history for this request.
```

Someone else have this problem?
How can I solve it?

Mac OS X 10.11.4 | 15 inch | Late 2011

Comment: Sounds like an encryption issue, please, contact support@paw.cloud, so that we can debug it with you.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it.
There was an encryption problem caused by my 2nd keychain (that was setted as default).
Switched back on the standard keychain (login), rebooted, activated paw and switched back on mi old keychain.

Comment: I fixed it by deleting the app from the Applications folder then delete `~/Library/Containers/com.luckymarmot.Paw/Data/Library/Application Support/Paw` and delete `~/Library/Containers/com.luckymarmot.Paw/Data/Library/Application Support/com.luckymarmot.Paw`

Comment: i only had to delete `~/Library/Containers/com.luckymarmot.Paw/Data/Library/Application Support/com.luckymarmot.Paw` and it fixed it.

Comment: Deleting `~/Library/Containers/com.luckymarmot.Paw/Data/Library/Application\ Support/com.luckymarmot.Paw` did it for me